# WCF Slow in Visual Studio, Quick in SoapUI

Tags: c#, performance, wcf, soap

I have a WCF service that I'm hosting on my internal network using a normal BasicHttpBinding with no security.

When I use SoapUI to test one of the methods in the service it's taking approximately 7ms to run.

When I use Visual Studio and let it stub out the Service Reference for me it is taking approximately 500ms to run.

My WCF service is hosted in a console application and I have the method in question writing out the service side code execution time to the console.  It is consistently running in about 7ms, even when I call it from Visual Studio (this seems to correspond the time I'm getting in SoapUI).

Obviously there must be some performance issue when using the .Net service reference objects but I'm not sure why.  Perhaps it's because I'm not setting something on the client side object that .Net has stubbed out for me?

Is there any way to tell what is causing the performance issue?

Here is the code that I'm using to benchmark on the client side:

```
        EnforcerServiceClient myClient = new EnforcerServiceClient();  //This is my service

        DateTime dtStart;

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            dtStart = DateTime.Now;
            myClient.AddOrUpdateRecipient("session", new Recipient());

            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Subtract(dtStart).TotalMilliseconds);
        }
```

Thanks.

-Scott

Answer (score 0):

After running through Fiddler and Wireshark captures it seems as though the response was being received within 10ms but the benchmark in Visual Studio still was showing 500ms.

Based on this, I knew something must have been tampering with the communication in the middle.  It turns out the Trend-Micro virus scanner has a proxy that HTTP communication was being funneled through and was causing the delay.

SoapUI wasn't using the proxy but Visual Studio was respecting it and this caused the difference in speed.

I turned off the virus scanner and now the service is functioning quickly.